# when escape key is pressed in a row in datagridview then text should be deleted from that row

Tags: c#

I am getting an error in row validating when I press the escape key. Instead of deleting the text from the datagridview row i.e I added text in a new row. I don't want to save that row and I don't want to close the form. Simply, when I press the Escape key from the keyboard the text should be deleted. I am using this code in datagridviewrow validating event.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgTests.CurrentRow.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString()) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dgTests.CurrentRow.Cells["Column2"].Value.ToString()))
{
    dgTests.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Column1 should not be empty";
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Please show what Event that this code resides in.. it will help in guiding others in regards to what code or suggestions to make

Comment: This validation says if the row has no text to throw an error. youre deleting the text and wondering why you get an error? am i missing something?

Comment: datagridviews have an internal list of all the rows that belong to them, if you dont want to save it and want to blank it why not just find the index of the selected row when you press esc and then remove the row from the internal list? that way the validation doesnt need to change and you get rid of the row you dont want?

Answer (score 1):

When Press escape Key in DataGridView I want to visible it false

in datagridview properties KeyPress write below code

```
if (Keys.Escape.ToString() == "Escape")
            gvExpireDate.Visible = false;

private void DatagridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(Keys.Escape.ToString());
        if (Keys.Escape.ToString() == "Escape")
            gvExpireDate.Visible = false;
        //if(e.KeyChar == Keys.Escape)

    }
```